# Remove the last 16 digits at the end of text

Tags: vbscript

I have a string that looks like this

```
[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834
```

I want to remove the digits at the end of the string. basically the 16 digits at the end of the string. This is the code I have wrote so far

```
txt="[APPLE PIE] Sei Shoujo Sentai Lakers 3 Battle Team Lakers 3 (100% FULL-PIC)_20121104_032834"
alert(Left(txt,75))
```

The problem is the string will be different so each will have different amount of characters. So how I remove the digits at the end of the string in vbscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead

```
Mid(txt,1,len(txt)-16)
```

regardless of the length of your string TXT, the last 16 characters will not be taken

Answer (score 0):

Just use LEN to calculate string lenght and subtract the ammount of characters you want to remove:

```
Left(txt,LEN(txt) - 16)
```